# R: Best match comparison

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, match

I have a long frame file like the following:

```
df <- structure(list(Date =c("2011-01", "2011-08", "2012-03", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", 
                   "2011-01", "2011-08", "2012-03", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08",
                   "2011-01", "2011-08", "2012-03", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08"),
     Part=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
     method=c("Type1","Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4","Type4",
              "Type1","Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4","Type4",
              "Type1","Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4","Type4"),
     value= c(4L, 46L, 43L, 9L, 8L, 46L, 63L, 84L, 2L, 5L, 78L, 2L, 89L, 2L, 6L, 62L, 25L, 46L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 24L, 13L, 21L, 19L, 8L, 3L)),
     class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -27L))
```

I would like to create another column called `BestMethod`. The variable should be a list of methods corresponding with the value closest to Type 3 by part and date.

For example, on 2011-01 for Part A, Type 1,2,3 were applied and Type 1 was the closest to Type 3. Under `BestMethod`, I would have Type1. Otherwise if all 3 types were not applied, I would put NA.

(In excel it may look like this:

```
=INDEX(C2:F2, MATCH(MIN(ABS(C2:F2-B2)), ABS(C2:F2-B2),0))
```

then this:

```
=IF(B2="", "NA", INDEX($C$1:$F$1,1,(MATCH(H2,C2:F2,0)))))
```

Then I would like to create another column called `FinalMethod`. I would like to have the most listed type for each part to be copied for all the dates.

For example. On 2011-01, 2011-02 for Part A, Type 1 was the better match but on 2011-03 Type 2 was the better match. In this case, I would like for Type 1 to be the `FinalMethod` for all dates for this part.

I tried the following:

```
which(abs(x-your.number)==min(abs(x-your.number)))
```

but am everying trouble calling the correct data values in and running it through each row.

Thanks.

Desired output:

```
df <- structure(list(Date =c("2011-01", "2011-08", "2012-03", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", 
                   "2011-01", "2011-08", "2012-03", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08",
                   "2011-01", "2011-08", "2012-03", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08", "2011-01", "2011-08"),
     Part=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
     method=c("Type1","Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4","Type4",
              "Type1","Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4","Type4",
              "Type1","Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4","Type4"),
     value= c(4L, 46L, 43L, 9L, 8L, 46L, 63L, 84L, 2L, 5L, 78L, 2L, 89L, 2L, 6L, 62L, 25L, 46L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 24L, 13L, 21L, 19L, 8L, 3L),
     BestModel=c("Type2", "Type1", "NA", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                 "Type1", "Type1Type4", "NA", "Type1", "Type1Type4", "Type1", "Type1Type4","Type1", "Type1Type4",
                 "Type2", "Type2", "NA",  "Type2", "Type2",  "Type2", "Type2",  "Type2", "Type2"), 
     FinalModel= c("Type1Type2", "Type1Type2","Type1Type2", "Type1Type2","Type1Type2", "Type1Type2","Type1Type2","Type1Type2","Type1Type2",
                   "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1","Type1", "Type1", "Type1", 
                   "Type2", "Type2","Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2","Type2", "Type2", "Type2")), 
     class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -27L))
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What does "closest to Type 3" mean? Type 3 is present only for dates: 2013-08 and 2013-09 for A, B and C while the other two types are not. In the example only Type 1 is present at date 2011-01. Could you make the example and the requested output a bit more clear?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for noting that. I have changed the dates so there are overlaps. For those without Type3, I would like to default to NA. Example: For part A, if type 1 is the closest to type 3 on 2011-01 then print type 1 under column BestMethod. If there is no type 3, then print NA under column BestMethod. 2nd part: For part A, if number of total type 1 is greater than total type 2 for all dates, then print type 1 under FinalMethod. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add to the post the desired output?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I will add it. Please let me know if you there's anything I can clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not very elegant solution using `dplyr` + `tidyr`, but works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

temp = df %>%
  group_by(Part, Date) %>%
  mutate(value.x = ifelse(method == "Type3", value, NA)) %>%
  fill(value.x, .direction = "up") %>%
  fill(value.x) %>%
  mutate(difference = abs(value.x - value)) %>%
  filter(method != "Type3") %>%
  filter(difference == min(difference)) 

BestMethod = temp %>%
  summarize(BestMethod = paste(method, collapse = " ")) 

FinalMethod = temp %>%
  group_by(Part, method) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  filter(count == max(count)) %>%
  rename(FinalMethod = method)

df %>%
  full_join(BestMethod) %>%
  full_join(FinalMethod) %>%
  select(-count) %>%
  arrange(Part, Date)
```

**Result:**

```
      Date Part method value  BestMethod FinalMethod
1  2011-01    A  Type1     4       Type2       Type1
2  2011-01    A  Type1     4       Type2       Type2
3  2011-01    A  Type2     9       Type2       Type1
4  2011-01    A  Type2     9       Type2       Type2
5  2011-01    A  Type3    46       Type2       Type1
6  2011-01    A  Type3    46       Type2       Type2
7  2011-01    A  Type4    84       Type2       Type1
8  2011-01    A  Type4    84       Type2       Type2
9  2011-08    A  Type1    46       Type1       Type1
10 2011-08    A  Type1    46       Type1       Type2
11 2011-08    A  Type2     8       Type1       Type1
12 2011-08    A  Type2     8       Type1       Type2
13 2011-08    A  Type3    63       Type1       Type1
14 2011-08    A  Type3    63       Type1       Type2
15 2011-08    A  Type4     2       Type1       Type1
16 2011-08    A  Type4     2       Type1       Type2
17 2012-03    A  Type1    43        <NA>       Type1
18 2012-03    A  Type1    43        <NA>       Type2
19 2011-01    B  Type1     5       Type1       Type1
20 2011-01    B  Type2    89       Type1       Type1
21 2011-01    B  Type3     6       Type1       Type1
22 2011-01    B  Type4    25       Type1       Type1
23 2011-08    B  Type1    78 Type1 Type4       Type1
24 2011-08    B  Type2     2 Type1 Type4       Type1
25 2011-08    B  Type3    62 Type1 Type4       Type1
26 2011-08    B  Type4    46 Type1 Type4       Type1
27 2012-03    B  Type1     2        <NA>       Type1
28 2011-01    C  Type1     3       Type2       Type2
29 2011-01    C  Type2    24       Type2       Type2
30 2011-01    C  Type3    21       Type2       Type2
31 2011-01    C  Type4     8       Type2       Type2
32 2011-08    C  Type1     4       Type2       Type2
33 2011-08    C  Type2    13       Type2       Type2
34 2011-08    C  Type3    19       Type2       Type2
35 2011-08    C  Type4     3       Type2       Type2
36 2012-03    C  Type1     7        <NA>       Type2
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Is there any way to do the same but for more than 3 type of methods? My actual data has 4 types of methods and I am unsure of how to do so without using your ifelse statement.

Comment: @flightless13wings In this case, would you be comparing to `"Type3"` or `"Type4"`? The code should not change for your case except for the reference `Type`. You should post the actual data if my code is not working for what you have.

Comment: I've edited the data to include a 4th method. The logic is the same as the one you used in your solution only now I would be comparing Type1,2, and 4 to Type 3. Then selecting the one the occurs the most for finalmethod. I didn't post the actual file since it is much too large and contains some confidential info. Hopefully, this sample data will mimic mine better. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @flightless13wings See my update. Only one small change: added `fill(value.x) %>%` after `fill(value.x, .direction = "up") %>%` in the first block. This ensures that NA's are filled correctly, since `Type4` is below `Type3` after sorted the dataset.